# how to make editable text in edit case using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like every table have their edit button :

```
<table class="table-responsive table-striped  col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 padding_left_right_none dash_table">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 130px;">
      <p class="name"><?php echo $aircrews->fname.'&nbsp;'.$aircrews->lname;  ?></p>
      <input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $aircrews->fname.'&nbsp;'.$aircrews->lname;  ?>" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40px;">
      <p class="name"><?php echo $aircrews->pay_status1;  ?></p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay1" value="<?php echo $aircrews->pay_status1;  ?>" style="height: 22px;width: 20px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40px;">
      <p class="name"><?php echo $aircrews->pay_status2;  ?></p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay2" value="<?php echo $aircrews->pay_status2;  ?>" style="height: 22px;width: 20px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td class="right_set"><button class="edit_btn">Edit / -</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that when I click on particular edit then its corresponding `p` tag should be hidden and input type=text should be visible but in my case, by clicking on "edit" button, every `p` tag getting hide and showing all input text instead of particular tags.

My jQuery code is given below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').hide();
     $(this).on('click', function(){
        alert('ok');
        $('.name').hide();
        $('.text').show();
     })
   })
   </script>
```

I am a new be here can anyone please help me related this? thanx in advance. I want only clickable edit open their text boxes instead how cs

My view is like this :
https://screenshots.firefox.com/9zlXPAB2kw8MYxR7/localhost

i want click on edit and name pay1 and pay2 should be text

Comment: $('.name').on('click', function(){
 $(this).next('input.text').show();
 $(this).hide();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.class` delcarations since the event will apply to every one of them in `.hide()` and `.show()`. Put the `click` event directly on all `p` in this case. (Can easily be adjusted to your specs).

Put `this` instead of your class in `'show()` and `hide()`. To show the current `<td>`s `.text` class you can use the jQuery `.siblings()` function and specificy the `.text` sibling directly.

**EDIT:**

Since you want to have the text change when you hit the `Edit` button and not each `p` then you can place `p` with `.edit_btn`, and traverse up and down the DOM using `.parent()` and `.children()` functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text').hide();
  $('.edit_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).parent().siblings('td').children('p').hide();
    $(this).parent().siblings('td').children('.text').show();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-responsive table-striped  col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 padding_left_right_none dash_table">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 130px;">
      <p class="name">
Name      </p>
      <input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $aircrews->fname.'&nbsp;'.$aircrews->lname;  ?>" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40px;">
      <p class="name">
name      </p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay1" value="<?php echo $aircrews->pay_status1;  ?>" style="height: 22px;width: 20px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40px;">
      <p class="name">
name      </p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay2" value="<?php echo $aircrews->pay_status2;  ?>" style="height: 22px;width: 20px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td class="right_set"><button class="edit_btn">Edit / -</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: see my image ur code is not working it not change the td to input

Comment: $(this).siblings('.text').show(); this is not working

Comment: I've edited my answer. I'm assuming you want the event to happen when you click the `Edit` button, but you never stated this in your original question.

Comment: thanx its working and i want also that hide the edit button and same size save button will be created after click

Comment: @Shruti, create a new question instead of adding requirements to this one and I'd be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the elements by class. `$('.name')` returns all elements of class name, also `$('.text')` returns all elements of class text, not just the one you clicked on.
So you need to give individual elements unique ids and select by id `$('#id')`.
See https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You should change Javascript part like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.edit_btn').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parents().siblings().children('p').hide();
      })
    })
</script>
```

In jQuery, `.parents()` function will check for the parents of "edit_btn" class which is `<td>`. Then `.siblings()` function consider all the siblings of `<td>` tag which comes under the same `<tr>` tag. Then `.children('p')` function will check for childrens with `<p>` tag means it consider `<p>` tags which are under those `<td>` tags and then `hide()` function will hide that particular `<p>` tag. Check below Snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit_btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents().siblings().children('p').hide();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-responsive table-striped  col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 padding_left_right_none dash_table">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 130px;">
      <p class="name">Name 1_1</p>
      <input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="Value Here 1_1" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 130px;">
      <p class="name">Name 2_1</p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay1" value="Value Here 2_1" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 80px;">
      <p class="name">Name 3_1</p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay2" value="Value Here 3_1" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td class="right_set"><button class="edit_btn">Edit / -</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="width:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 130px;">
      <p class="name">Name 2_1</p>
      <input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="Value Here 2_1" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 80px;">
      <p class="name">Name 2_2</p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay1" value="Value Here 2_2" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 80px;">
      <p class="name">Name 2_3</p>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="pay2" value="Value Here 2_3" style="height: 22px;width: 110px;border: none;text-align: center;">
    </td>
    <td class="right_set"><button class="edit_btn">Edit / -</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```